# How to one hot encode a list of different "columns" to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I need to prepare my data for modelling and I want to create a dataframe with 0-1 values for the columns. I have a list with different columns which i want to one hot encode into a dataframe.

```
List = [['DRT', 'AFV'], ['CLN', 'DRT', 'AFV'], ['CLN', 'DRT', 'AFV'], ['BLN', 'PCK', 'CAL', 'WBL', 'BCO', 'UPG', 'CLN', 'DRT'], ['BLN', 'AFV', 'CAL', 'WBL', 'UPG', 'CLN', 'DRT'], ['COA', 'BLN', 'PCK', 'CAL', 'WBL', 'UPG', 'CLN', 'DRT'], ['COA', 'BLN', 'PCK', 'CAL', 'WBL', 'UPG', 'CLN', 'DRT']]
```

I want to have a dataframe as shown below with 1 values for the items in the list and 0 values that are not in the list, and then different rows for each list in this list. There are a total of 28 different values that can be in the list.

[![df][1]][1]

I tried "get_dummies" but this creates different columns like 1_DRT ... 7_DRT because of the different locations of DRT in the dataframe. Also tried using some functions from Scikitlearn but without succes. Would really appreciate some help with this one.

Edit: Columns of the eventual dataframe with the 0-1 values -->

columns=['CLN', 'AFV', 'DRT', 'CAL', 'WBL', 'BLN', 'UPG', 'BCO', 'PCK',
'COA', 'WPK', 'WCO', '1CL', 'DRY', 'RES', 'WFR', 'FRZ', 'REC',
'CHF', 'STP', 'DFR', 'HOT', 'EXT', 'PIL', 'SPL', 'INS', 'SVT',
'UVP']
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuUp9.png

Comment: What does each nested list mean? You have more than one record of CLN, for instance. What do you expect to find in the CLN column of your output?

Comment: A list in the list represents the different operations done on a certain object. For each list I want to create a row that gives 1 values for the operations done on the object and 0 values for the operations that arent done. So the first object has undergone 'DRT', 'AFV' and not the 26 other operations, and I would expect a row in the dataframe that gives a 1 value for only these two operations. I would like to add that idealy I want to have the output as a 28 column data frame with "AFV" and "PCK" as target label. Normally the list would contain more items with more operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Pandas Series for `List` and `.explode()` the list into different rows and then use `.str.get_dummies()` to get the dummy table for each explode row.  Aggregate the rows of original list by `.max(level=0)`:

```
df = pd.Series(List).explode().str.get_dummies().max(level=0)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   AFV  BCO  BLN  CAL  CLN  COA  DRT  PCK  UPG  WBL
0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
2    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
3    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1
4    1    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1
5    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
6    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: And there it is! I think this is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot :)